# Alter fixed and random effects using Fixef and VarCorr in package simr with a ZIP glmmTMB

Tags: r, glmmtmb

I am trying to alter the fixed and random effects of a zero-inflated Poisson model using R's `glmmTMB` function. I want to input the altered fixed effects into the `powerSim` function. Here is the data:

```
sample <- as.data.frame(cbind(1:50, (rep(1:10, each = 5))))

#randomize interventions by clinic
ru1 <- cbind(rbinom(10, 1, 0.5), 1:10)
ru2 <- cbind(rbinom(10, 1, 0.5), 1:10)

#merge randomization id with original sample 
sample <- merge(sample, ru1, by = "V2") %>% merge(ru2)

#add days 
sample <- as.data.frame(cbind(sample, scale(rep(-546:546, each = 50))))

#order by clinic and prescriber
sample <- sample[order(sample$V2, sample$V1.x),]

#simulate ZIP distribution for days supply
set.seed(789)
sample <- cbind(sample, ifelse(rbinom(54650, 1, p = 0.5) > 0, 0, rpois(54650, 5)))

#rename variables
sample <- rename(sample, pres = V1.x, clinic = V2, aj = V1.y, def = V1, 
                 days = `scale(rep(-546:546, each = 50))`, 
                 dayssply = `ifelse(rbinom(54650, 1, p = 0.5) > 0, 0, rpois(54650, 5))`)

#days truncated
sample$days_ <- ifelse(0 > sample$days, 0, sample$days)

#model 
m1 <- glmmTMB(dayssply ~ aj*days_ + (1|clinic/pres), zi = ~ aj*days_, 
        data = sample, family = poisson)
```

After a lot of trial and error, I finally figured out how to specify the conditional fixed effect using the fixef function:

```
fixef(m1)$cond [["aj"]]
```

But when I try to change it to the desired fixed effect for the power analysis, I get the error that "cond is not the name of a fixed effect." Not sure if this is a syntax related issue, or if fixef doesn't work for zero-inflated models.

I would also like to alter the variances for the random effects using VarCorr.